# How to Import all Methods Under Umbrella Alias in Python

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a `services` folder which has an `__init__.py`.

It has an `__all__` method like below:

```
__all__ = [
    "get_customer_from_foo_api",
    "get_store_from_foo_api",
    "get_something_else_from_foo_api"
```

I then import that module wherever I need it, e.g.: `from ...services import (get_customer_from_foo_api, get_store_from_foo_api,...)`

My goal is to be able to import all "get from foo API" methods as `foo_api` and then use them as `foo_api.get_customer(id)`, etc to avoid redundancy in naming.

Is there some import syntax I could use to accomplish this or do I pretty much need a class that serves as a facade? Is there a better approach to this? I am coming from the .NET world (this is a Python question, just context if anyone wants to reference C#, JavaScript, etc). We are using FastAPI on this project.

Comment: You could just import the module itself with `import services` and use them. If you really care about the name you could give it an identifier like `import services as foo_api`

Comment: Thanks, that might be exactly what I am looking for. Trying now.